# How to convert a url that has a space in it to a valid url in java?

Tags: java, url

I have a link that has a space in it, but when i paste it to the browser, it loads the page and the link changes slightly, here is the link:

```
http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/DUZELTME/dvm/screenshot 7-500x500.jpg
```

But it returns into the following when browser loas the page:

```
http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/DUZELTME/dvm/screenshot%207-500x500.jpg
```

Here is what i do in java:

```
 public static Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String link) throws URISyntaxException {
    try {
        URI uri = new URI(link);
        URL url = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
        InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("HATA", "THERE is an error", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the problem is, I get the following exception:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 73:
```

So, can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `java.net.URI` class may be able to help you here - its single argument constructor expects the argument to be a proper URI with illegal characters escaped, but its multiple-argument constructors can handle un-escaped parts.  If your initial URL does not contain any %-escapes already, and does not have a `#` fragment on the end then you can do

```
String escaped = new URI("dummy", unescaped, null).getRawSchemeSpecificPart();
```

The trick here is that the three-argument constructor expects a "scheme", a "scheme-specific part" and a "fragment", all in unescaped form.  So for your example in the question

```
new URI("dummy", unescaped, null)
```

will give you the properly-escaped URI

```
dummy:http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/DUZELTME/dvm/screenshot%207-500x500.jpg
```

Extracting the raw SSP from that URI will give you everything after the first colon, i.e.

```
http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/DUZELTME/dvm/screenshot%207-500x500.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing proper URL parsing with Java standard library is far from trivial. I grew frustrated when hitting edge cases. So I developed a library for proper URL parsing in Java: [galimatias](https://github.com/smola/galimatias). Any URL that works in a web browser should work with galimatias.

With `io.mola.galimatias.URL.parse(link)` you get a `io.mola.galimatias.URL` object. Here parsing will work with almost whatever you throw at it (unless it can't really be interpreted as a URL). Then you can transform it to a Java URL with `toJavaURL()`.

For your use case, you would write:

```java
 public static Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String link) {
     try {
         URL url = io.mola.galimatias.URL.parse(link).toJavaURL();
         InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
         Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
         return d;
     } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e("HATA", "THERE is an error", e);
         return null;
     } catch (GalimatiasParseError e) {
         Log.e("HATA", "THERE is an error", e);
         return null;
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         Log.e("HATA", "THERE is an error", e);
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

The URL must be encoded, and [Java has an object for that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html). Use `URLEncode.encode()` on your string.

Comment: No, URLEncoder does `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not URI encoding - it will convert space to + rather than %20, and will also encode the existing slashes as %2F.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I should have read the question closer. +1 for your answer, quite informative.